# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space potentially from an immutable list?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, immutability

I have implemented a class named BusinessData. The constructor takes a number of double arrays, but I want the double arrays to be immutable, so I have implemented this class a value object. I used an immutable collection for the double arrays.

However, I am getting an OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space. I think it has something to do with the garbage collection and the converting of array to List, then converting it back to an array. I am doing this since I am unable to change the constructor, or the method signature.

Are there any better solutions that use less memory? I understand that my implementation uses a lot of memory. Thank you.

```
public class BusinessData implements Business{

    // Using an immutable collection to make data of report immutable
    private final String name;
    private final double commissionPerEmployee;
    private List<Double> firstData;
    private List<Double> secondData;
    private List<Double> thirdData;

    public BusinessData(String name,
                      double commissionPerEmployee,
                      double[] firstData,
                      double[] secondData,
                      double[] thirdData) {

        this.name = name;
        this.commissionPerEmployee = commissionPerEmployee;

        if (firstData == null) {
            this.firstData = null;
        } else {
            this.firstData = Collections.unmodifiableList(DoubleStream.of(firstData).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));;
        }

        if (secondData == null) {
            this.secondData = null;
        } else {
            this.secondData = Collections.unmodifiableList(DoubleStream.of(secondData).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));;
        }

        if (thirdData == null) {
            this.thirdData = null;
        } else {
            this.thirdData = Collections.unmodifiableList(DoubleStream.of(thirdData).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBusinessName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public double getIncome() {
        return commissionPerEmployee;
    }


    @Override
    public double[] getFirstData() {
        if (firstData == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return firstData.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x).toArray();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public double[] getSecondData() {
        if (secondData == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return secondData.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x).toArray();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public double[] getThirdData() {
        if (thirdData == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return thirdData.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x).toArray();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Business that = (Business) object;
        return Objects.equals(this.getBusinessName(), that.getBusinessName()) &&
                Objects.equals(this.getIncome(), that.getIncome()) &&               
                Objects.equals(this.getFirstData(), that.getLegalData()) &&
                Objects.equals(this.getSecondData(), that.getLegalData()) &&
                Objects.equals(this.getThirdData(), that.getLegalData());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, commissionPerEmployee, firstData, secondData, thirdData);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I change the Lists to static, it does not give me the error anymore. However, I don't think I should do that.